# Display stored Array Objects to List in Javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, display

I'm Trying to make a list display in HTML of the stored details i put in my object using Javascript.
which should look like this

```
name: Tester1 , age: 1
name: Tester2 , age: 2
name: Tester3 , age: 3
```

I used **for in** loop to display all the inputted objects, but it this happened

```
Actual:
name: Tester1 , age: 1name: Tester1 , age: 1name: Tester2 , age: 2name: Tester1 , age: 1name: Tester2 , age: 2name: Tester3 , age: 3
```

Here is the code for the Jascript

```
var person = [];
function profile(e) {
    //to stop form from resubmitting
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var pProfile = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        age: document.getElementById('age').value
    }
    person.push(pProfile);
    //used to convert result to string
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(person);

    document.forms[0].reset();

    //display in Final Obejct div 
    document.getElementById("fObject").innerHTML = myJSON;

    //display converted objects to
    for (let x in person){
         document.getElementById("rFormat").append("name: " + person[x].name + " , " + "age : " + person[x].age + "<br>");
         console.log(person[x]);
    }
}
```

And this is for the HTML

```
    <div id="part1">
        <h3>Part 1</h2>
        <form id="profile" onsubmit="profile(event)" action="#">
            Name: <input type="text" id ="name">
            Age: <input type="text" id ="age">
            <input type="Submit" value="Add">           
        </form>

        <h4>Final Object</h4>
        <div id="fObject"></div>

        <h4>Readable Format</h4>
        <div id="rFormat"></div>
    </div>
```

Pretty sure that I did something wrong with the **for in** loop, but i don't know exactly where. 
Please help. I'm new in javascript. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `append()` try with `insertAdjacentHTML()` or `innerHTML`. You also do not need the loop (since you are updating the HTML in each click), you can simply populate the last item in the array:

```js
var person = [{name: "Tester1",age: 1 },{name: "Tester2",age: 2 },{name: "Tester3",age: 3 }];
var person = [];
function profile(e) {
  //to stop form from resubmitting
  e.preventDefault(); 

  var pProfile = {
      name: document.getElementById('name').value,
      age: document.getElementById('age').value
  }
  person.push(pProfile);
  //used to convert result to string
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(person);

  document.forms[0].reset();

  //display in Final Obejct div 
  document.getElementById("fObject").innerHTML = myJSON;

  //display converted objects to
  var p = person[person.length-1]; //last item in the array
  document.getElementById("rFormat").innerHTML += "name: " + p.name + ", " + "age : " + p.age + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="part1">
  <h3>Part 1</h2>
  <form id="profile" onsubmit="profile(event)" action="#">
      Name: <input type="text" id ="name">
      Age: <input type="text" id ="age">
      <input type="Submit" value="Add">           
  </form>

  <h4>Final Object</h4>
  <div id="fObject"></div>

  <h4>Readable Format</h4>
  <div id="rFormat"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`person` is an array. use `for of`. Then use x directly.

`for in` is for objects. If you use it on an array, you will just get the index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `for-loop` to use `for-of` instead of `for-in`. You need the values and not the keys

```
for(let x of person)
```

and then instead of `person[x]`, you already have the object you need so use as below

```
.append("name: " + x.name + " , " + "age : " + x.age
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is by using the **innerHTML** method instead:

```
for (let x in person) {
    document.getElementById("rFormat").innerHTML += person[0] + "<br>";
}
```

I am not sure as to why yours does not work though.